# Json schema exception no protocol error when creating a metadata type in Mule using a Json schema

Tags: json, mule, jsonschema, anypoint-studio, metadatatype

I am adding a metadata type in Mule 3.8.1 using a JSON schema called stores.json which contains a property that references an organization.json schema

```
"organization": {
  "$ref": "definitions/common/organization.json"
},
```

but I am getting the error:

```
Error creating metadata... 
org.mule.common.metadata.parser.json.SchemaException:
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
definitions/common/organization.json
```

The organization.json schema is located at: **src/main/api/schemas/definitions/common** and the stores.json is located at: **src/main/api/schemas**

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the entire schema? Have you set the `id` field?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating the metadata in a currently older version of Anypoint Studio which probably has a bug for reading the schema. Mule Runtime 3.x doesn't create the metadata. Try the current version of Anypoint Studio (6.5.x at this time) to check if it is fixed.